# ¿Cómo manejar una conexión websocket en redux de manera apropiada?

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, redux, react-redux

Estoy tratando de crear y manejar una conexión websocket (para un chat simple) en una aplicación web, hecha con [react](/questions/tagged/react), [redux](/questions/tagged/redux) y por parte de la `API` con [express](/questions/tagged/express), mi implementación es la siguiente:

```
// redux.store.js
const middlewares = [reduxLogger, socketIoMiddleware];
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);
const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer];
const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(...enhancers);
const reduxStore = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);

export default reduxStore;
```

Siguiendo [**esta recomendación**](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live) de la documentación de redux, cree mi propio `middleware` para manejar todo lo relacionado con mis eventos real-time, cuya implementación es la siguiente:

```
// socket.io.middleware.js
const socketIoMiddleware = () => {
  const socket = createSocketIoConnection();

  return (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    socket.on('newMessage', (message) => store.dispatch(setMessage(message)));

    if (action.type === setMessage.toString()) {
      socket.emit('sendNewMessage', action.payload);
    }

    if (action.type === setUsername.toString()) {
      socket.emit('registerUsername', action.payload);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
};
```

**Mi problema es:** cuando el evento `socket.on('newMessage')` se ejecuta por primera vez, lo hace bien, llega el mensaje y el contenido esperado, pero cada vez que llega un mensaje nuevo subsecuente al primero empiezan a duplicarse los `dispatch` del evento `setMessage` lo que lleva a que los mensajes se dupliquen y el rendimiento se pierda por completo dado la cantidad de eventos disparados,

#### Aquí un ejemplo del comportamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los dos repositorios en Github por si desean revisar la implementación:

[Socket.IO API Implementation](https://github.com/jorius/xrp-rt-svc) 
[Socket.IO UI React Implementation](https://github.com/jorius/rct-rt-ui)

Gracias.